# SQL Server doesn't use a suggested index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, querying

First, I am using: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)

I have created a table that looks like this:

```
 create table dbo.pos_key
 ( keyid                           int identity(1,1)     not null
 , systemid                        int                   not null
 , partyid                         int                   not null
 , portfolioid                     int                       null
 , instrumentid                    int                   not null
 , security_no                     decimal(10,0)             null
 , entry_date                      datetime              not null
 )
```

keyid is a clustered primary key.  My table has about 144,000 rows.  Currently systemId doesn't have much fluctuation, it is the same in every row except 1.
Now I perform the following query:

```
select *
  from pos_key
 where systemid = 33000
   and portfolioid = 150444
   and instrumentid = 639
```

Which returns 1 row after a clustered index scan. [pos_key].[PK_pos_key]
Execution plan said that expected row count was 1.082

SQL Server quickly suggests that I add an index.

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_SYS_PORT_INST
 ON [dbo].[pos_key] ([systemid],[portfolioid],[instrumentid])
```

So I do and run the query again.
Surprisingly SQL-server doesn't use the new index, instead it again goes for the same clustered index scan and but now it claims to expect 4087 rows!  It however doesn't suggest any new index this time.

To get it to use the new index I have done the following:

- Updated table statistics (update statistics)
- Updated index statistics (update statistics)
- Dropped cached execution plans related to this queries (DBCC FREEPROCCACHE)

No luck, SQL server always goes for the clustered scan and expects 4087 rows.

Index statistics look like this:

```
All Density      Average Length   Columns                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.5              4                systemid                        
6.095331E-05     7.446431         systemid, portfolioid           
1.862301E-05     11.44643         systemid, portfolioid, instrumentid
6.9314E-06       15.44643         systemid, portfolioid, instrumentid, keyid
```

Curiously I left this overnight and in the morning ran the query again and BAMM now it hits the index.  I dropped the index, ran the select and then created the index again. Now SQL server is back to 4087 expected rows and clustered index scan.

So what am I missing.  The index obviously works but SQL server doesn't want to use it right away.

- Is the of fluctuation in systemId somehow causing trouble?
- Is DBCC FREEPROCCACHE not enough to get rid of cached execution plans?
- Are the ways of SQL-Server just mysterious?

Comment: what estimated row count do you get for each predicate individually? i.e. if you look at the estimated plans for three queries each one with a single one of the conditions?

Comment: Can you script your table with inserts in a file and share it? I tried too reproduce it filling the table with my values with the distribution similar to yours, and 1) there was no index suggestion 2) the density for 3 columns reflects correctly the situation and the estimation is also correct in my case

Comment: @MartinSmith Exected row counts are like this:

With SystemId: 144270
With PortfolioId: 26730

Comment: @MartinSmith Exected row counts are like this:

With SystemId: 144270 = 100%
With PortfolioId: 26730 = 18,53%
With InstrumentId: 16446 = 11,40%

These numbers happen to be the same as if I did max of count(*) when grouping by say portfolioId.  

However grouping by all 3 and taking the max of count(*) doesn't give 4087.  3rd place is however very close 4074.

Comment: `144270 * (144270/144270.0 * 26730/144270.0 * 16446/144270.0)` is `3047` so based on the assumption that the values are independent you would expect that to be the estimate. Are the values not independent and correlated?

Comment: Well you shouldn't really always expect the worst case scenario and again 3047 is lower than 4087.  As you see in the statistics the combined statistic for these 3 columns is 1.862301E-05 = 0.01862301% which give 2,68 rows.  This is exactly what the plan said once the index stated kicking in (hours later).

All values are independent but not evenly distributed.  Some portfolios have a lot of assets and some instruments, like currencies, are much more common than others.

Answer (score 0):

With a composite index and all columns used in equality predicates, specify the most selective column first (`portfolieid` here). SQL Server maintains a histogram only for the first column.

With the less selective column first, SQL Server probably overestimated the row count and chose to the clustered index scan instead thinking it was more efficient since you are selecting all columns.

Comment: SQL Server will auto create stats on the other columns though. theres no reason why it should only use that uninformative two value histogram.